# Two asynchronous codes in two different files. I want them to run one by one but they run at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code in the second file depends upon the first one so I want the first file code to execute first and when the first file code completes it's execution then the code in second file should run. The code in the first file basically stores the image in the google cloud bucket and then return the URL of that image and second file updates the post schema in MongoDB and pushes the URL string in the images array. Since the code in both files runs side by side and the code in the second files does not wait for first one to execute the post schema is updated even before the first code returns all the string url's which is a problem. I want to get all the string url's first and then update the post schema.

**So in first file I have**

```
function sendUploadsToGCS(req, res, next){
  if(!req.files){
    return next();
  }

 req.files.map((image, index) => {
  const gcsname = uuid() + image.originalname;
  const file = craigFilesBucket.file(gcsname);

  const stream = file.createWriteStream({
    metadata: {
      contentType: image.mimetype,
    }
  });

  stream.on('error', err =>{
    req.files[index].cloudStorageError = err;
    next(err);
  });

  stream.on('finish',  async () => {
    req.files[index].cloudStorageObject = gcsname;
    await file.makePublic();
    req.files[index].cloudStoragePublicUrl = getPublicUrl(gcsname);
    console.log(req.files[index].cloudStoragePublicUrl);
    next();
  });

  stream.end(image.buffer);
})

}
```

**In the second file I have**

```
const addImagestoPost = async (req, res, next) =>{
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if(!errors.isEmpty()){
    return next(new HttpError('Invalid inputs passed, please check your data.', 422))
  }

  const postId = req.params.pid;

  let post;
  try{
    post = await Post.findById(postId);
  }catch(err){
    const error = new HttpError(
      'Something went wrong could not update post',
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }
  // if(!req.files[0] || !req.files[0].cloudStoragePublicUrl){
  //   return next(new HttpError('cloudStoragePublicUrl err.', 422))
  // }
  //images: req.files.cloudStoragePublicUrl,
  console.log('HEllo World');




  try{
    await post.save();
  }catch(err){
    const error = new HttpError(
      'Something went wrong, could not update post', 500
    )
  }

  res.status(200).json({post: post.toObject({getters: true})})
}
```

Comment: both functions should async, Now create a single file, load both function from both files and using await.

For more info: https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/

Comment: You're using `async` / `await`. Why? How can you adopt this to solve your problem?

Comment: await actually halt the execution of the function until it completes the current execution. 
eg: await func1() 
      await funct2()

now funct2() won't start executing until func1 completes its execution

Answer (score 1):

You may arrange your code like mentioned below:

```
const func1 = require(from file 1);
const func2 = require(from file 2);
async function load() {
    const result1 = await func1();
    const result2 = await func2()
 }
```